# In Spacy is it possible to do both statistical and rule-based sentence splitting?

Tags: spacy

I am using spacy 3.6 currently.

I have documents that have both punctuation and eol splits.  This is how the data I received works.  Too much data to preprocess myself for a consistent representation.  What I would want to do is first have the statistical component recognize the punctuation instead of using a rule-based approach to try to handle punctuation which would be a mess.  Then, take the results of that split and split everywhere I see an eol character which reliably in my case does signal a sentence break.

Example:
`This is a good sentence.  This too is a good sentence.\n For sure this a new sentence\n Dr. Smith, would you please toss me another Sprite?`

In the example above there are 4 sentences.  Note if done incorrectly, the first list ending in period and eol could potentially trigger an extra blank sentence, however statistical processing should remove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I can think of a way to get at what I want, indirectly.  So not the answer to the question I asked, but maybe the answer to the question I should have asked?

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
text = 'This is a good sentence.  This too is a good sentence.\n For sure this a new sentence\n Dr. Smith, would you please toss me another Sprite?'
lines = text.split('\n')
docs = []
for line in lines:
     docs.append(nlp(line))
whole_doc = Doc.from_docs(docs)
```

Then I would have the output I would expect as outlined above.